# IntelliJ "Looking for Usages" freezes when refactoring/renaming enum entry

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-15

I am using IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 16 Preview (version IC-144.4199.23). I need to rename a couple Enum entries using IDEA's Refactoring system.

For instance, I currently have an enum entry named `black`, and I need to rename it and its usages to `BLACK`, which I do by Right-clicking the entry, selecting `Refactor -> Rename...`, and entering `BLACK`.

The problem is that IDEA prompts me with the `Looking for Usages` progress dialog, freezes the dialog, and never actually refactors the entry name.

This issue is pretty odd, because when I use `Find Usages` on the entry directly, it perfectly says that there is "No usages found in Project Files" (which is normal). However, the aforementioned dialog freezes at a roughly 99% progress bar in searching for occurrences, and does not proceed in renaming the entry.

**Edit: Issue also applies to IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.2, apparently.**

Comment: Given all the known bugs in intellij  stable releases, you're  brave for doing anything with an EAP other than check the new features, if you can even do that.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils I've been using the v16 EAPs for the past month, and I haven't really gone into issues that affect my experience. It appears that the issue is present in IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.2, too.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with 15.0.4; granted I don't know the exact scenario. I refactored an enum across a number of packages; worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

When you click the type of refactoring, make sure that in the 'Choose scope where change signature may occur:' you **DO NOT choose "All Files"**, but rather something else - such as "Project Files". Otherwise, it's going to take forever!